# Actionscript 3 - How do I make new instances draggable?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I am attempting to build a drag and drop game where a user can build something using the images I provide. I will have images in a menu that the user can click and drag to the building area. The user will be able to add however many instances of that image as they want.

I was able to get part of it working. So far, I can click the image and drag it around, and create as many instances as I want. However, **I cannot click and drag the image once I have placed it.**

When I do a trace to see what the name is, it says that all the new instances are named hillChild1. I tried to make them named hillChild1, hillChild2, etc., but that doesn't seem to work either... not sure that is an issue, though.

Here's my code:

```
thesubmenu1.hill.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDown);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onUp);

var myImage:Sprite = Sprite(new Hill_mc());
var i:Number=0; i++;


function onDown(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var myImage:Sprite = Sprite(new Hill_mc());
    myImage.name = "hillChild"+i;
    addChild(myImage);
    myImage.x = mouseX;
    myImage.y = mouseY;
    myImage.startDrag();
    myImage.buttonMode = true;
}
function onUp(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var myImage:Sprite = Sprite(new Hill_mc());
    myImage.stopDrag();
    myImage.name = "hillChild";
}



stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, traceName);
function traceName(event:MouseEvent):void { trace(event.target.name); }



myImage.getChild(myImage).addEventListener("mouseDown", mouseDownHandler);
stage.addEventListener("mouseUp", mouseUpHandler);

function mouseDownHandler (e:MouseEvent):void{
   myImage.startDrag();
}
function mouseUpHandler (e:MouseEvent):void{
   myImage.stopDrag();
}
```

I am new to StackOverflow and also Actionscript 3, if it isn't apparent.

Comment: Just an FYI, There's no need to cast as Sprite.  `var myImage:Sprite = new Hill_mc();` will work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is likely that you are creating a new instance on mouse up (when what you want is a reference to instance that was already created on mouse down). Also, you never add a click listener to you new objects.  Add the mouse up listener to stage only after the mouse down (then remove the listener in the mouse up).

```
thesubmenu1.hill.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, createCopy);

var i:int=0;
var tmpImage:Sprite; //to store which image is being dragged currently

function createCopy(e:MouseEvent):void {
    tmpImage = new Hill_mc();
    tmpImage.name = "hillChild"+(i++); //increment every copy
    addChild(tmpImage);
    tmpImage.x = mouseX;
    tmpImage.y = mouseY;
    tmpImage.startDrag();
    tmpImage.buttonMode = true;
    tmpImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDown); //add the mouse down to this new object
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onUp); //since the mouse is currently down, we need to listen for mouse up to tell the current copy to stop dragging
}

//this will be called when click a copy
function onDown(e:MouseEvent):void {
    tmpImage = Sprite(e.currentTarget); //get a reference to the one that was clicked, so we know which object to stop dragging on the global mouse up.
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onUp); //listen for the mouse up
    tmpImage.startDrag();
}
function onUp(e:MouseEvent):void {
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,onUp); //now that the mouse is released, stop listening for mouse up
    tmpImage.stopDrag(); //stop dragging the one that was clicked
}
```

Comment: Oh my gosh! You are a life saver! I have spent almost 3 whole days trying everything I could find...